# Store textbox values in php array

Tags: php, html, forms, textbox

So basically I have the user enter a number on my first screen.
Here is test1.php which generates the number of text boxes that the user had previously entered. That number is $input

```
echo "<form action='test2.php' method='post'>";
for($i=1; $i<=$input; $i++)
{
     echo "Entry $i";
     echo "<input type='text' name='Names'>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' class='button' name='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Then my test2.php should print all the values entered, but it only prints out the last value entered from test1.php. For example is $input is 4, only the text entered in the 4th text box prints, which is understandable as I don't know how to print all values.

```
$names=$_POST['Names'];
foreach($number as $num){
       echo $num;
}
```

Is the problem with the name I gave to the textboxes, or something else?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a name grouping attribute, so that you'll get an array of inputs instead of just one:

```
<input type='text' name='Names[]'>
                           // ^ this is important
```

Sidenote:

I don't know if this is a typo, but this should be `$names` instead of `$number`:

```
$names = $_POST['Names'];
foreach($names as $num){
       echo $num . '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bmYDGS)

Comment: @MattScottGibbs sure no prob, glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you give the same name to all of your input (in your test1.php) so when you try to restore them on your test2.php, your `$_POST['Names']` just takes the last input with this name.

A solution is to give a different name to all of your input

In yout first file use it :

```
echo "<form action='test2.php' method='post'>";
for($i=1; $i<=$input; $i++)
{
    echo "Entry $i";
    echo "<input type='text' name='".$i."'>";
}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='input' value='".$input."'>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='button' name='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

And in your 2nd file :

```
for($i=1; $i<=$_POST['input']; $i++){
    echo $_POST['$i'];
}
```

Comment: Using an integer as id/name is not a good idea, at least prepend some string

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="myform">
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="101"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="102"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="103"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="104"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="submit"/>
</form>



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach($_POST['array'] as $myarray) {

    echo $myarray.'<br>';

}
```

## OUTPUT

```
101
102
103
104
```